# Checking if a sum is an integer or float

Tags: python-3.x

I know there are a few topics about this but I have tried using `isinstance` i have tried `type()` and also

```
if type(NumGiven) == int : print "This number is an int"
elif type(NumGiven) == float : print "This number is a float"
```

But they all just give me output of blank line.

This is my code:

```
 NumGiven=''
while not NumGiven.isnumeric():
   NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
while len(NumGiven)<7 or len(NumGiven)>8:
   NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))

if len(NumGiven)==8:
   my_list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven]
   print(sum([int(i) for i in NumGiven])/10.0)
```

So as you can see I need it to tell the user if the sum (at the end when dividing by 10) is a float or an integer.

Comment: `inNumber` doesn't appear anywhere in your code. What does `print(inNumber)` or `print(type(inNumber))` do?

Comment: Sorry , I just realised it was just an example , let me change it.EDIT:instead of inNumber I changed it to my variable 'NumGiven' , is that correct ?

Comment: if you test the `type()` of `NumGiven`, it will always be `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if `x/10` is `float` or `int`, you can simply check if `x` is a multiple of 10 or not.
Here is the code to demonstrate the fact:

```
NumGiven = ''
while not NumGiven.isnumeric():
    NumGiven = (input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
while len(NumGiven) < 7 or len(NumGiven) > 8:
    NumGiven = (input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))

if len(NumGiven) == 8:
    my_list = [int(i) for i in NumGiven]
    temp = sum([int(i) for i in NumGiven])
    ans = temp / 10.0

    if temp % 10 == 0:
        print("int")
    else:
        print("float")
```

Live demo - [int](http://ideone.com/K7Lwv1)/[float](http://ideone.com/yjX9BJ)

For a more general solution, you might be interested in [this standard library function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer).

Comment: Wow , I literally did the same thing but instead of '0' I either put ==float or ==int , anyway thanks , I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem! You can upvote and accept my answer to close the question if you are satifsfied.

Comment: @Ireallyneddhelp you can give it an upvote too! ( shameless request I know :D )

Comment: I cant too low rank.